# Iframe login authentication

Tags: php, html, iframe

The site that i am putting in my iframe has a login authentication. Is there any script that my iframe would automatically login to that website by putting my own username password? Thanks!

Comment: Is the website from the same domain as yours? If not, that'll put a damper on things

Comment: if your own site then just remove the authentication.

Comment: what if not same domain? is it possible to have a script that automatically logs in?

Comment: this is sounding very shaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is sending the data through a form, just get the id of the form and the edit the `value` property of the elements you need to enter in.

Then submit the form using the form.submit() method.

If not you will need to know more about what method it uses to send data.

It may be as simple as calling the onclick() function of a button on the page.